# Can't assign value to instance variable

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Here is a case where I am passing some parameters to a method, and then assigning the parameter values to local ivars and properties:

```
- (void) assignOwnerView:(UIView*)oView andPosition:(menuPosition)position withTopView:(UIView*)topView {


    self.topView = topView;
    self.ownerView = oView;
    self.position = position;

    << --- other code --- >>
}
```

The interface for these properties is this (UPDATED with SYNTHESIS)

```
@interface MenuVC (){
    UIView *ownerView_;
    UIView *topView_;
    menuPosition position_;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *ownerView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *topView;
@property (assign) menuPosition position;

@end


@implementation MenuVC
@synthesize list, menuDelegate;
@synthesize ownerView = ownerView_;
@synthesize topView = topView_;
@synthesize position = position_;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style
{...
```

The enum is defined here:

```
typedef enum {
    above,
    below,
    centered
} menuPosition;
```

After executing the three assignments, at a breakpoint in the debugger, the values are as shown below:

[image]

The received parameter values look okay, but the assigned values of the ivars `ownerView_` and `position_` are not right. On the other hand, `topView` is okay.

The same thing happened when I assigned directly to ivars rather than properties.

I started seeing this problem when I upgraded to Lion (10.7.3) and XCode 4.3.1. It was working okay before then. I see this at other spots in my app, and I don't see any pattern to it yet.

ARC is not being used.

I reported this problem before, but didn't get an answer. In this case, the problem description is a simpler. That might make it easier to see what the problem is.

UPDATE -- header file added

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class MenuVC;

@protocol menuDelegateProtocol 

typedef enum {
    above,
    below,
    centered
} menuPosition;


- (void) didSelectItemFromMenu:(MenuVC *)menu atIndex:(NSUInteger) index;

@end

@interface MenuVC : UITableViewController {

    NSArray *list;

    float extendedHeight;

    id<menuDelegateProtocol> menuDelegate;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *list;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<menuDelegateProtocol> menuDelegate;

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style;
- (void) hide;
- (void) unhide;
- (void) assignOwnerView:(UIView*)oView andPosition:(menuPosition)position withTopView:(UIView*)topView;

@end
```

Comment: Can we see your synthesize statements?  Your naming choices look like the could be the culprit.  Also, an example of the inputs that are producing that debug screen couldn’t hurt.

Comment: Okay, the synthesis statements are up now. I must have hit cancel when I updated the first time.

Comment: Try NSLog()ing the values out. The debugger might be confused (this is even more likely with optimizations turned on).

Comment: Vincent, that seems to have resolved the problem. NSLog is showing reasonable values that are different form what the debugger is showing. Do you know why this happens and what I can do to get the debugger to report properly? If you want to post that this as an answer, I'll check it.

Comment: Jim, I don't know, but I think this is worth filing a bug at https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the debugger to GDB from LLDB. This seems to be a problem with LLDB. I'm not seeing this now.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't synthesized the properties.

Put:

```
@synthetize ownerView = ownerView_;
@synthetize topView = topView_;
@synthetize position = position_;
```

After "@implementation MenuVC".

Comment: Yes, I did. I updated the question to show this. Maybe there is something wrong with it though. That wouldn't explain why it doesn't work with assigning it to iVars directly, though.  Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Jim Have you tried cleaning and building your project again? This line: "@interface MenuVC () {" does not compile, change it to "@interface MenuVC : NSObject {".

Comment: I tried a clean build and that didn't work. The use of () is correct for implementing an extension which is what this is. (Chapter 6 of "The Objective-C Programming Language.") The main interface is in the header file, and this extension is in the .m file. Since the .h file is not too complicated, I will add it to the original question.

Comment: @Jim Well, it works for me, but having ivars inside a category seems strange, have you tried moving them to the .h? What compiler are you using?

Comment: It's not a category, it's an extension.

Comment: @Jim Sure, and you can only have ivars inside of it when using LLVM. You are using LLVM right?

Comment: I am using LLVM, but extensions and this feature are not only supported in LLVM.

Comment: From Apple's Documentation: " Using the Clang/LLVM 2.0 compiler, you can also declare properties and instance variables in a class extension."